# Rancher can pull images from private registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry, rancher

I have create a private registry by harbor.
but when I use rancher to update a container, rancher can not  pull images.
before this [registry.ziztour.com](http://registry.ziztour.com/index.php?s=/Home/User/login/from/1.html)  is normal operation.

Rancher registries:
[image: rancher registryies]

Error:
[image: error]

Manually pull my private registry image successful:

rancher v1.1.0
docker v1.11.2

Comment: A standard question: what's in logs?

Comment: Does it also fail when you add a (standalone) container in infrastructure -> Hosts ?

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, but when I had issues pulling from a secure registry I solved the issue by creating/modifying the `etc/docker/daemon.json` file on the rancher server and all rancher hosts and adding the following.

```
{
"insecure-registries" : [
"<registry-1-ip>",
"<registry-2-ip>"
]
}
```

Once you've done this run `sudo service docker restart`

When you add the ip's leave the http:// or https:// off.

Make sure you do this on all your rancher hosts as well as on the rancher server, otherwise it won't work.